# Python tests coverage report by module

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py, python-coverage

I'm using Coverage to measure the code coverage of my tests, which outputs XML / HTML coverage statistics by file.

Is there a way to output the results by python **module** instead? For example:

```
- module a - 70%
  - module a.b - 80%
  - module a.c - 60%
- module b - 90%
```

Comment: If you are ok with hosted solutions you could use Codecov. Here is an example: https://codecov.io/github/pyca/cryptography